# In case of a growing project, it is better to keep a single static library or create more than one, each for a single source code group?

Tags: c++, compilation, c++17, static-libraries

I have the following doubt on how to proceed with my project. Let's suppose my project is structured in this way:

```
project/
├── src/
│   ├── group_1/
│   │   ├── class_1
│   │   ├── class_2
│   │   ├── class_3
│   ├── group_2/
│   │   ├── class_1a
│   │   ├── class_2a
│   │   ├── class_3a
│   ├── group_3/
│   │   ├── class_1b
│   │   ├── class_2b
│   │   ├── class_b
```

Therefore I have a `src` folder which contains 3 kind of files (`group_1`, `group_2` and `group_3`) and each of them has its proper source files and some of one group may be included in some of another group. From now on, I have compiled the code and created a single static library, let's call it `libproject.a`. So, to compile a program which uses one of the headers defined in my project I simply had to add the `-lproject` flag.

Of course, the project is growing and since time passes I am adding more and more source files to each group and each of them is becoming more and more complex.

So, I was wondering if, from the point of view of the performance, it would be better to compile and create a single static library for each group of files (so one for `group_1`, one for `group_2` and one for `group_3`).

The other thing I was wondering is that, in the case in which I would create more libraries, I would have to link them every time I compile a code which contains my headers (defined in `project`), adding the flag `-lgrouplibrary`. Does this unnecessarily "complicate" the compilation part? The problem is that more flags would be required in the case in which I would like to use functions from more headers of different group in a single program.

What would be the best way to proceed in order to don't complicate too much the compilation part, but optimizing the performaces?

Comment: Draw a dependency diagram.  When a dependency is changed, what will need to be compiled or rebuilt?  How often are these dependencies changed?  One reason for using libraries is to contain code that is mature and doesn't change a lot.

Comment: Sorry, but asking for opinions is not appropriate on Stackoverflow, can you [edit] your question, reframing it so it can be answered with facts and citations?

Comment: Don't worry too much about compiler options getting too complicated. There are ways of organizing your project in a way that drastically reduces the complexity. E.g. with cmake you can set up a library target in a way that other targets get linked to the linking target too and all those targets could come with info like include directories attached... As for "the best" design: this really depends on the details. Does it make sense for the parts to be used on their own? Are the components interdependent? ...

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Dependency diagram is drawn at the beginning of the question. Compilation is a complicated process of course, I have a long makefile for it. I rebuild the library every time something changes of course.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I slightly edited the question.

Comment: @fabian let's say that some libraries are used together, some other can be used separately. It depends.

Comment: Again, the question is asking for a "better" way to do something, which is mostly opinion, and purely subjective. The problem here is that if you ask ten C++ developers what is the "better" way to do something you will get at least eleven different answers. This is purely opinion, rather than something that can be answered with facts and citations.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I edited again the question removing all opinion-based references